# Does a multivariate polynomial stay irreducible in transcendental field extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, multivariate-polynomial

If $F$ is an algebraically closed field, and $p \in F[X_1, ..., X_n]$ irreducible, and $K$ a (transcendental) field extension of $F$, is $p$ always irreducible in $K$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X = \mathrm{Spec}\, F[X_1,...,X_n]/p$. Then $X$ is an irreducible scheme over a separably (even algebraically) closed field $F$. Now the following result holds.

[Lemma 33.8.3 in stacks project Part 2](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/020J)
*Let $X$ be an scheme over a separably closed field $F$. If $X$ is irreducible, then for every field extension $F\subseteq K$ scheme $X_K = \mathrm{Spec\, K}\times_{\mathrm{Spec}\,F}X$ is irreducible.*

Since in our case $X_K=\mathrm{Spec}\, K[X_1,...,X_n]/p$, we derive that $p$ is irreducible in $K[X_1,...,X_n]$.

Comment: Is there a more intuitive explanation for why this is true? If one extends the field of coefficients to rational functions in some of the variables $X_i$ why can it not lead to splitting some irreducible polynomials?

Comment: @Conifold for purely transcendental extensions it can be proved without resorting to more complex argument. Namely let $A$ be a commutative algebra over algebraically closed field $k$ with a unique prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$. Let $k\subseteq k(X_i\,|\,i\in I)$ be a purely transcendental extension of $k$. Consider $B = k[X_i\,|\,i\in I]$. Then we have an exact sequence: $$0\rightarrow  B\otimes_k\mathfrak{p}\rightarrow A[X_i\,|\,i\in I]\rightarrow (A/\mathfrak{p})[X_i\,|\,i\in I]\rightarrow 0$$

Comment: Since $\mathfrak{p}$ consists of nilpotent elements, we derive that $B\otimes_k\mathfrak{p}$ also consists of nilpotent elements. We also deduce that $(A/\mathfrak{p})[X_i\,|\,i\in I]$ is a domain. Thus $B\otimes_k\mathfrak{p}$ is a unique minimal prime ideal of $A[X_i\,|\,i\in I]$. Now localizing we deduce that $A\otimes_kk(X_i\,|\,i\in I)$ has a unique maximal ideal.

Comment: The point is that not every transcendental extension is pure. For this one needs more subtle argument.